# Why do Angular guards behave differently when using @select from @angular/redux-store

Tags: javascript, angular, redux, observable

- I have an Angular setup that uses two guard. `canLoad` and `canActivate`
- both get fed with the same observable from the @angular-redux/store via `@select`

**Question**: Why does `canActivate` work with the observable that `@select` returns while `canLoad` breaks all routing from then on? What is the difference between the two guards?

Related angular issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18991

**auth.guard.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanLoad, CanActivate {

  @select() readonly authenticated$: Observable<boolean>; // @angular-redux/store

  canLoad(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    // return true; // works
    return this.authenticated$; // ERROR: all routing stops from and to the current page
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    // return true; // works
    return this.authenticated$; // works
  }

}
```

**app-routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SomeAComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'someb',
    component: SomeBComponent,
    canActivate: [
      AuthGuard
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'lazy',
    loadChildren: './lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule',
    canLoad: [
      AuthGuard
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: '/'
  }
];
```

Comment: Does it work when the `canLoad()` guard is used on a component and not a lazy-loaded module ? I believe it's linked to the RouterPreloader that doesn't load `canLoad` routes. From the `router_preloader.d.ts` file :
`
 * If a route is protected by `canLoad` guards, the preloaded will not load it.
`

Comment: I thought `canLoad()` is only used for lazy-loaded modules? What would you expect when using it on an already loaded module?

Comment: As mentioned in the github issue the observable should be completed. I'm not sure if `@select() readonly authenticated$.` completes. If not, `take(1)` in theory can't be what I'm looking for as it does not get me the latest update from the store (http://rxmarbles.com/#take).

Comment: Makes sense, I didn't really use `canLoad()`, but it seems a bit weird tbh

Comment: Have you find solution to this problem?? I just ran into issue that guards works correctly but says store is not configured when I'm in guarded route

Comment: I'm waiting for the angular issue to be resolved. They are working on it :)

Answer (score 1):

The same issue I had, so to resolve it and let working in both CanLoad and CanActivate, you should add operator take(1)

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanLoad, CanActivate {

  @select() readonly authenticated$: Observable<boolean>; // @angular-redux/store

  canLoad(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    // return true; // works
    return this.authenticated$.pipe(take(1));
  }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    // return true; // works
    return this.authenticated$; 
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into the same issue and I do think that this is a bug in angular. I ended up just rewriting my guard to store a local variable that is populated by subscribing to the Observable. I am using ngrx/store here.

```
@Injectable()
export class MustBeAuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate, CanLoad {

  constructor(private store: Store<fromAuth.State>) {
    store.select(fromAuth.authenticated)
      .subscribe((authenticated) => {
        this.authenticated = authenticated;
      });
  }

  private authenticated: boolean

  canLoad(): boolean {
    return this.isAuthenticated();
  }

  canActivate(): boolean {
    return this.isAuthenticated();
  }

  private isAuthenticated() {
    if (!this.authenticated) {
      this.store.dispatch(new SignIn());
    }
    return this.authenticated;
  }
}
```